# stm32f103 - 16 bit mode SPI reading returns 0xFFFF

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, serial, stm32f10x

I am working with a sensor which communicates through SPI. I am

trying to read MISO line, but it returns 0xFFFF. first I send 0xC000 on

MOSI and the sensor places 0x0032 on MISO. I read MISO using oscilloscope,

but in code, this value is 0xFFFF. I tried to send dummy data but nothing

changed. here is my code:

```
#include "stm32f10x_spi.h"
#include "delay.h"

#define SPIx_RCC      RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1
#define SPIx          SPI1
#define SPI_GPIO_RCC  RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA
#define SPI_GPIO      GPIOA
#define SPI_PIN_MOSI  GPIO_Pin_7
#define SPI_PIN_MISO  GPIO_Pin_6
#define SPI_PIN_SCK   GPIO_Pin_5
#define SPI_PIN_SS    GPIO_Pin_4

uint16_t data;

SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure; 
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
int main(void)
{
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(SPIx_RCC, ENABLE);
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode=SPI_Mode_Master;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_High;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_16b;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler=SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_256;
SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS=SPI_NSS_Soft | SPI_NSSInternalSoft_Set;
SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);
SPI_Cmd(SPIx, ENABLE);

  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(SPI_GPIO_RCC, ENABLE);
// GPIO pins for MOSI, MISO, and SCK
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = SPI_PIN_MOSI | SPI_PIN_MISO | SPI_PIN_SCK;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(SPI_GPIO, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = SPI_PIN_SS;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(SPI_GPIO, &GPIO_InitStruct);


RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE );
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_2 | GPIO_Pin_3 | GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

while(1){
    SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4B01);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
    SPI_GPIO->BSRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    // delay for applying setting stably
    delay_ms(2);
    SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x4C00);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
    //while (SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY));
    SPI_GPIO->BSRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    delay_ms(2);

    SPI_GPIO->BRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0xC000);
    //SPI_I2S_SendData(SPIx, 0x8000);
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)));
    while (!(SPIx->SR & (SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE)));
    data=SPI_I2S_ReceiveData(SPIx);
    // data is always 0xffff which should be 0x0032
    SPI_GPIO->BSRR = SPI_PIN_SS;
    delay_ms(1);
    }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Error is in code not shown, e.g. pin configuration.

Comment: Thanks @TurboJ '#define SPI_PIN_SS    GPIO_Pin_4' . I am using port A.

Comment: Dear @TurboJ , as I mentioned, I checked the MISO signal using oscilloscope and read the correct data, but in code, I can't capture the right value. It means pin configurations is OK.

Comment: You're not showing how (or even if) you're configuring the port pins.

Comment: Dear @brhans , I edited the question and inserted full code.

Comment: Looks like you're configuring MISO as an output...

Comment: @brhans , it is configured as Alternate Function, not output.

Comment: If you stop asserting the select pin low, and instead tie MISO low with a small value resistor, does the received value change?  Perhaps you should try directly operating the SPI registers.  Also you might momentarily try 8-bit mode and see if it's any different - at this level you wouldn't be trying to talk to a peripheral but just seeing that MISO is captured.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisStratton for comment. My sensor supports 16 bit spi communication and not 8 bit (I have not examined 8 bit communication!). I did not understand your last sentence.

Comment: As I said, you *would not be trying to talk to a peripheral* but only to verify that the state of MISO which you ground through a small resistor is captured.  So it doesn't matter what your peripheral supports.

Comment: For that matter you could also test that the pin works as a GPIO input.  Electrical damage is not the most likely explanation, but it is possible.  It seems like the alternate function remap configuration should default to the way you want to use it, but you could also explicitly set that.

Comment: The SPI1_MISO function can be mapped to different pins. You'll need to configure that pin remapping too. Look at the AFIO_MAPR register.

Comment: @brhans The reset value of this register is zero which maps pins as NSS/PA4, SCK/PA5, MISO/PA6, MOSI/PA7 , so I think it is not required to configure remapping.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should be required, no, but it's worth setting or at least printing the mapping in effect to be sure.  Also as mentioned before it might be worth testing the pin as a GPIO input, obviously using different code.  And check for hairline solder defects or adjacent pin shorts, too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton , yes, I agree.